# Where to see how long I have been a member of SO?

Tags: support, profile-page

If I go on and check other user's profile I can see like "Member for 1 year, 5 months" etc.. Where should I check so that I can know the same for my own profile?

Comment: You are *7 months* old.. Go to your profile page :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Can you see your own ?

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: Could u plz tell me where exacly u can see that in the profile page?

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. There's a _"profile"_ button at the top when you go to your own page. You first land on _"activity"_, click on _"profile"_ to go back to your public profile.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5898312/tony-vincent?tab=profile) is a direct link to your profile.

Comment: Toolbar at the top of the browser page, click on your avatar.  Click around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Comment: And make sure that you're viewing the *full site*, and not the *mobile* version of the web site.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee?tab=profile shows me my own profile.  I've been a member for 5 years, 1 month.  Substitute [your own user ID](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5898312/tripleee?tab=profile) into the URL to see your own, if you can't otherwise figure it out; but it was a simple matter on clicking on my avatar and then the "profile" tab.

Comment: It used to be enough to enough to check a menu option in the browser (Chrome Android) to make it fetch the desktop version of the site. Now I have to actively click the **full site** link at the bottom of the page to get the correct profile page. Maybe this is related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that on your profile:

- Click on your [name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5898312/tony-vincent) in the topbar

  - You'll see your user page, with the activity tab active
- Click at the left, near the the top on the tab called [*profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5898312/tony-vincent?tab=profile)

  - You'll see your user page, with the profile tab active
- Look at the right-hand side of the page

  - under your location and webiste (if you entered that) you'll find how long you're a member.

Or if you're still puzzled:

[image: profile page, how long you're a member]

As an alternative you can use a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/552386?UserId=5898312) or call the [Stack API/users/{id} endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=5898312&filter=!G*klMw.RxZafdkfHbpHJAdO1-7&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to get the raw data.